# how do you quote multiple values with the helm quote function?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

for example instead of this:

```
name: {{ $value.derps | quote }}
```

can I do something like this?

```
name: {{ {{ $value.derps }}-{{ $.Release.Namespace }} | quote }}
```

what is the right syntax for that if its possible. often I want to use multiple values and would like to wrap  the final concatenated string with quotes

I also am doing this inside range:

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.SomeConfig }}
    name: {{ $value.derps }}-{{ $.Release.Namespace }} # want to quote this
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options work but now I'm confused about the utility of the quote function - it seems pretty useless.

This:

```
  name: "{{ $value.certName }}-{{ $.Release.Namespace }}"
```

Is a lot nicer than this

```
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s" $value.certName - $.Release.Namespace | quote }}
```

The quote function doesn't make sense to me. I'm not sure why I see it in all the examples.

Comment: The function exists because your value might, in some cases, have a double quote in it. This is usually unlikely though.

Comment: gotcha so it does some escaping that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like this?

```
{{- $temp := $value.derps  "-" $.Release.Namespace -}}
name: {{ $temp | quote}}
```

or

```
name: "{{ $value.derps }}-{{ $.Release.Namespace }}"
```

Comment: is that the only way? can this be on one line?

Comment: name: {{ (.Values.derps  "-" .Values.herps) | quote }}

Comment: ^ that works for you? I get `at <$value.derps>: derps is not a method but has arguments`

Comment: Can you share your values.yaml file

Comment: see at my question i want to append namespace and im doing this inside of range

Comment: Can you try all inside quotes? "{{ $value.derps }}-{{ $.Release.Namespace }}"

Comment: looks like that works so then wants the point of the quote function does it do other stuff?